# v.distance.buffer does not create proper buffers with flat endcaps

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, buffer

I try to create flat end buffers for each of my line segments in QGIS (with Grass-algorithm v.buffer.distance).

If I use the tool with straight lines there is no problem creating the flat end buffer polygons but if i use my digitized line which is not straight i end up with strange artefacts as you can see in this screenshot:
( The left side buffers are the ones created by the tool and the ones on the right side are just there to demonstrate the way it roughly should look like.)

[image]

Is there a way I can prevent the flat-end-buffer-tool from creating these strange buffer polygons?

**Edit1:**

I tried the v.parallel-Tool but this also creates strange artefacts:

Result of v.buffer.distance:
[image]

Result of v.parallel:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have described already, you have segmented line features... that's why.

[image]

Merge your digitized lines into single line then try again.

[EDIT] Workflow the image below was created:

1. Merge the segments into single line.
2. Activate **v.parallel** and set Offsets =(same offset to both major and minor axis), set Side =(both), and check (Create buffer-like parallel lines).
3. After v.parallel creates lines, manually digitize to create polygons, using snapping to the line layer.

[image]

Not v.buffer answer, and I am not sure you'll like digitizing manually.... anyway.

Comment: Thanks but I need a flat end buffer polygon for every segment of my line, not for the hole line

Comment: @markgraeflerland Sorry I misunderstood your requirement. Are you thinking something like the additional image?

Comment: yes,a flat end buffer for every line segment (I dissolved the line by attributes before)

Comment: I tried v.parallel but this also creates strange artefacts (see edited question above)

Comment: @markgraeflerland It looks as though you have selected *Make outside corners round*. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: If I don't select "Make outside corners round" the parallel lines go totally crazy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqOTD.png

Comment: @markgraeflerland Ummm... yes, it is really awful. No idea of what is happening.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I have a similar problem...